# How to get specific id of a dropdown React?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I am a beginner in React and Spring Boot and I am trying to search a way to get the id value from a selected dropdown and pass it to an object. I have a dropdown that fetches data from Category class from Spring Boot

```
async componentDidMount() { 
     const response = await fetch('/api/categories'); // Fetch data from GET endpoint in Spring Boot
     const body = await response.json();
     this.setState({categories: body});
}
```

In render():

```
let optionList =
            categories.map (category =>
            <option value={category.id} key={category.id}>{category.categoryName}</option>
        )

return (
    // Other codes
    <FormGroup>
        <select>{optionList}</select>
    </FormGroup>
);
```

I am trying to pass the category.id here so every new object created can have a corresponding category to the category selected from dropdown

```
itemBlueprint = {
        description: '',
        category: {id: 1, categoryName: ''} // Currently hardcoded category id
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select comes with the handler `onChange` which gives an event argument to the callback handler.

```
const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(null)

const selectOnChange = (event) => {
  setSelectedCategory(event.target.value)
}

let optionList = categories.map(category =>
  <option value={category.id} key={category.id}>{category.categoryName}</option>
)

return (
  // Other codes
  <FormGroup>
      <select onChange={selectOnChange}>{optionList}</select>
  </FormGroup>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to do it inspired by your solution. If I may know, what do I search for when I want to learn about these event targets and when to use them?